# Не могу разобраться в каких словах ударение определяет семантику слова

Tags: семантика

Века уходят, и уходят люди —
Нет жизни рокового повторенья,
И лишь случайный отблеск озаренья Нетленной красотой всегда пребудет.
В заветный край пусти меня скорей.
Пусть сердце вновь неведомою птицей
Над голубым сиянием морей
На древний и неясный зов стремится.

Answer (score 2):

Век**а** - винительный падеж множественного числа, в**е**ка - родительный падеж единственного числа.

Роков**о**го - от "роковой" (судьба), р**о**кового - от "роковый" (музыкальный жанр).

Comment: Что слало с правилом "мы не делаем домашних заданий"?

Comment: @VictorBazarov Суть "не делать домашних заданий в том, чтобы провоцировать на самостоятельное изучение языка, при этом помощь в исправлении ошибок приветствуется. На подобное домашнее задание невозможно найти ответ в учебнике, тут или видишь, или нет. Поэтому на подобные задания, я считаю отвечать допустимо. Другое дело если они станут постоянными и станет понятно, что человек учится не хочет.

Однако сообщество может считать иначе и поставить мой ответ на удаление, не вижу в этом ничего плохого.

Comment: Отвечать на вопросы можно по-разному.  Помните притчу "дай человеку рыбу - он будет сыт на день, научи человека рыбачить - он будет сыт всю жизнь"?  Если бы Вы ответили, например, дав слово "рога" в качестве пояснения как ударение влияет на семантику, то, может быть, у задавшего вопрос появилось бы желание ещё раз поискать в тексте нужные слова...

Comment: Марк Из, любое домашнее задание можно сделать по учебнику, вы просто не читали подобных учебников. Другое дело, что тут человеку действительно непонятно, как делать домашнее задание, видимо из-за скудости словарного запаса. Так что по конкретному случаю я с вами соглашусь, можно и помочь.